# Android Home Screen App Icon With Unwanted Mini-Icon Badge

Tags: android, shortcut, homescreen

After adding code that populates the device's home screen with a shortcut icon for my app, the icon appears as an aliased icon, with the main icon I'm trying to install on the home page and a mini version of the icon that's some sort of badge at the lower-right corner of my icon.  Does anyone know how to prevent this badge from being displayed?

[image]

The EyeSee icon is the one for my app.  Note another app's icon above mine has a mini badge that is not the same as it's main icon.  I'd love to know how to create this alternate badge icon, but I'd be most grateful just to get rid of the mini alias icon - for now.

Here's my code for creating the shortcut when OnCreate runs for the main activity.

```
private void createOrUpdateShortcut()
{
    SharedPreferences appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean isAppInstalled = appPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled", false);

    if(!isAppInstalled) 
    {
        Context appContext = getApplicationContext();

        Intent homeScreenShortCut= new Intent(appContext, MainActivity.class);
        homeScreenShortCut.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        homeScreenShortCut.putExtra("duplicate", false);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 
        {
            homeScreenShortCut.setPackage(appContext.getPackageName());
            homeScreenShortCut.setClass(appContext, MainActivity.class);
            homeScreenShortCut.setClassName(appContext.getPackageName(), String.valueOf(MainActivity.class));

            ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
            assert shortcutManager != null;
            if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) 
            {
                ShortcutInfo pinShortcutInfo =
                        new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "browser-shortcut-")
                                .setShortLabel(appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                                .setLongLabel(appContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this,R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                                .setIntent(homeScreenShortCut)
                                .build();

                shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo, null);
                System.out.println("added_to_homescreen");
            } else {
                System.out.println("failed_to_add");
            }
        } else {
            if(shortcutReinstall) 
            {
                Intent removeIntent = new Intent();
                removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, homeScreenShortCut);
                String prevAppName = appPreferences.getString("appName", getString(R.string.app_name));
                removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, prevAppName);
                removeIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
                getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(removeIntent);
            }

            Intent addIntent = new Intent();
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, homeScreenShortCut);
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
            addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
        }

        //Make preference true
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled", true);
        editor.putString("phoneLanguage", currentLanguage);
        editor.putString("appName", getString(R.string.app_name));
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to prevent this badge from being displayed?

Generally speaking, that's not an option. The standard OS-supplied rendering of a pinned shortcut includes what you refer to as the badge, and there is no means of opting out of that badge. Presumably, that is to help avoid apps from masquerading as other apps via these shortcuts.

> Note another app's icon above mine has a mini badge that is not the same as it's main icon

I assume that you refer to "Patio Motion...". The larger icon is the icon for the *shortcut*. The smaller icon ("badge") in the lower right is the icon for the *app* (i.e., what shows up in Settings and elsewhere).

In your case, you appear to have set the shortcut icon to be the same as your launcher icon, which is why you have this duplicate effect. Use a different icon for the shortcut, ideally one that represents the action being taken by that shortcut.

As it stands, it seems like your shortcut is simply to launch your app, which is not what shortcuts are for. Most users can put a launcher icon on their home screen without the need for your app to publish a shortcut.

Comment: Thank you, CommonsWare, for your response!  Heuristically, I've observed that apps I installed from GPS seem to result in a home screen icon being created when mine were not.   So I thought that meant they were all creating shortcuts one time when their apps start for the first time.  How could these apps being installed result in a home screen icon without the app programmatically setting a shortcut?

Comment: @MKE: "I've observed that apps I installed from GPS seem to result in a home screen icon being created when mine were not" -- the behavior varies by launcher implementation. "How could these apps being installed result in a home screen icon without the app programmatically setting a shortcut?" -- the launcher is welcome to set  up icons. On the Pixel Launcher, there is a "Add apps to Home screen" setting that controls this, and other launchers will have their own take on that setting.

Comment: @MKE: From what I've seen, usually a launcher will only do this for apps installed via conventional means, instead of `adb`/IDE runs the way developers do.

Comment: so it sounds like it depends on how the device implements the launcher and this can vary among devices or manufacturers.  Thanks, again, for your feedback.  BTW, are you an expert on espresso testing, too?

Comment: @MKE: "so it sounds like it depends on how the device implements the launcher and this can vary among devices or manufacturers" -- correct. Also, there are hundreds upon hundreds of third-party launchers. For example, Nova Launcher has its own "Add icons to home screen" setting. "are you an expert on espresso testing, too?" -- not really, sorry.

Comment: nope, I was just trolling to see if you'd be willing to look at another question nobody else has been willing to comment on for some time